# Select objects after selecting a div and an index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of same-named divs inside the other div, I would like to select the first div inside the main div and continue selecting data inside it.

So this is what I did:

```
$('.main > div')[0]
```

But now I can't `$('.another')` from inside that selection.

How can I keep on selecting from inside the div I already selected?

Comment: you better add your `HTML` you are working on before you get down votes

Comment: I think what you are looking for is jQuery's `.first()` instead of `[0]`. Probably you wanna couple it with `.find()` so you can do `$('.main > div').first().find('.another')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

Use `.first()` instead of `[0]`. [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) is the proper jQuery way to get the first Element of your selection as a jQuery Object.

**Second:**

Find children of that div using `.find()`. With [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) you can search inside a jQuery Object for it's descendants using a selector.

`$('.main > div').first().find('.another')`
should do the job in your case.